# .NET direct webservice (SOAP) call (no WCF)

Tags: .net, web-services, wcf, security, soap

I want to know what is the most secure point to call a web service from .NET. I do not want to use WCF but still be able to rely on some security when sending messages using SOAP.

I want to be able to skip the C# code generation and use XML as input instead of a C# class. The XSD is generated based on a model and service definition (not as C# classes), only the SOAP header needs to be attached. I was planning to use XSLT to generate the final service call including the SOAP header and the XML payload.

Comment: WCF is microsoft's software stack to send and receive soap messages. Why would you think it's not secure?

Comment: I do not think it is not secure, but I do not want to use it because I do not want to use the code generation, I already have XML.

Comment: Do you mean you already have the xsd schema definition of your message types? Or just the actual XML payload of your message?

Comment: Both are available to me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I interpret your scenario/question correctly, you have a service definition defined in XML schema (and maybe a UML model), so you don’t want to replicate that definition in C# code. If that is the case, then you may want to look into “**contract first**” development options, such as the “Microsoft Contract-First Tool”.

> Service contracts often need to be created from *existing services*. In
>   .NET Framework 4.5, data contract classes can be created automatically
>   from existing services using the contract-first tool. To use the
>   contract-first tool, the XML schema definition file (XSD) must be
>   downloaded locally; the tool cannot import remote data contracts via
>   HTTP.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh674270%28v=vs.110%29.aspx
http://wscfblue.codeplex.com/